# SkyDrive silently crashing after "SkyDrive sync engine stopped working"

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

I received the message

> SkyDrive sync engine stopped working

when SkyDrive tried downloading a file that was currently in use on my system. Ever since then, SkyDrive has been silently crashing<sup>*****</sup> as soon as it tries communicating with the servers. The only time SkyDrive doesn't crash, is when my PC is offline.

SkyDrive itself doesn't seem to think there is anything wrong. Its icon in the File Explorer shows it's syncing, and the SkyDrive app pretends everything has been synced "6 seconds ago". Since I'm running Windows 8.1, there is no app for me to reinstall. What can I do to fix this?

---

<sup>*****</sup>: When hovering the mouse over the SkyDrive tray icon, the icon will simply disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I found to fix this constant crashing issue, is by moving my SkyDrive folder.

Simply right click on the SkyDrive folder, select **Properties**, go to the **Location** tab, click on the **Move...** buton and select another folder<sup>**1**</sup>.
Since the files aren't exactly "moved", but instead are copied to the target then deleted from the source, this process can take a while depending on the size of your SkyDrive folder and the speed of your storage drive.

If you wish, you can "move" your SkyDrive folder back to where it belonged<sup>**2**</sup> using the same method as described above, once the files have all been copied over.

---

<sup>**1**</sup>: It is recommended to create a new folder for that purpose.
<sup>**2**</sup>: You might need to create the previous SkyDrive folder again.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in Desktop and Laptop, but I found the solution.

In my case, I had several files with long names or names with double puntation or exclamation characters (Remove "!", ".."), I modified all. Many of files are Favorites.
Check your OneDrive Progess (Downloading or Updating) at what point crashes.

I hope I had been helpful

Greetings

Comment: Make sure the name of the file or folder doesn’t begin or end with a space, end with a period, or begin with two periods or include any of these characters: / \ < > : * " ? | Folders names or files that have character ! are ok. I have plenty files and folders names with ! so they are listed at the top when viewed alphabetical.. Characters that have " " are not allowed and probably " characters were causing the issue. You could run regex expression to remove invalid filenames and characters and check folder length. See stack question http://bit.ly/1KydOGf